# Effective way to check whether data exists and insert/update 100K records into Mysql Database

Tags: mysql

we are migrating data from one database to another database with some business condition. As a general we need to check whether a data exists in a table or not. if the data does not exists then insert else update. Currently it takes more time (~15 mins) for just 20K records. Can some one provide effective solution for check and insert/update.

Comment: Do you want to check if there's any data at all in a table or if there are data exists for a particular condition?

Comment: yes i need to check whether the same records in the database. if yes then i need to update. I also found the below link http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2008/04/fastest-way-to-insert-100k-registers.html  but it is not satify my checking condition.